# Why we generally normalize the feature but not input data?

Tags: sensor-data

In research papers where they use time-series data from motion sensors, to the best of my knowledge, they normalize the extracted features. Suppose that they use an accelerometer sensor with x, y, z-axis and each axis has a different range (x: -5 and +5, y: 0 and 20 and x: -10 and -30 (not experimental results, I wrote ranges randomly). If we extract mean, zero-crossing rate and 5 FFT as features and then normalize the extracted features for each axis, will the results not be problematic, especially for zero-crossing rate?

Why we do not simply normalize (ranges between 0-1 for ex.) the raw data and instead we normalize features? I do not understand.

Comment: What do you see as the benefit of normalization?

Comment: To give equal importance to each input while creating the model. I understand that normalizing features help with that but if we compute ZCR and then only normalize the features, I think it would mislead. Instead, normalizing input and then computing ZCR is makes more sense to me. But of course, I am not sure

Comment: Why would you want to assume equal importance?

Comment: We don't want that our model to focus only on a specific input and discard one or more types of input. For example, if we have some values between 1000-10000 (an input) and some values between 0.002-0.0003 and both two inputs are important for us. We don't want that our model discards the second one and give almost no importance to it.

Comment: Regression models are self-weighting so I'm not clear on this.